# Binding issue in ItemsControl within a UserControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, itemscontrol

I created a simple example which replicates the problem I am having with a much bigger usercontrol - application interaction. The controls have been changed to simplify, but reflect the exact problem.

I have a user control (CheckBoxTable) which creates a grid of checkboxes based upon the property CheckBoxData:

```xaml
<UserControl
    x:Class="WPFNotWorkingTest.CheckBoxTable"
    x:Name="CheckBoxTableName">
    <ItemsControl DataContext="{Binding ElementName=CheckBoxTableName}" ItemsSource="{Binding CheckBoxData}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding GridRow}" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding GridColumn}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid ShowGridLines="True" Style="{Binding Path=Style}" Loaded="OnGrid_Loaded"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckBoxChecked}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

The ItemSource CheckBoxData is an ObservableCollection within the CheckBoxTable user control.

```cs
public ObservableCollection<CheckBoxTableData> CheckBoxData
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<CheckBoxTableData>)GetValue(CheckBoxDataProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CheckBoxDataProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CheckBoxData.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckBoxDataProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("CheckBoxData", typeof(ObservableCollection<CheckBoxTableData>), typeof(CheckBoxTable), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(CheckBoxTable.OnCheckBoxData_Changed)));

private static void OnCheckBoxData_Changed(DependencyObject dObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBoxTable table = (CheckBoxTable)dObject;
    ObservableCollection<CheckBoxTableData> objOldValue = (ObservableCollection<CheckBoxTableData>)e.OldValue;
    if (objOldValue != null)
    {
        objOldValue.CollectionChanged -= table.OnTableData_CollectionChanged;
    }

    ObservableCollection<CheckBoxTableData> objNewValue = (ObservableCollection<CheckBoxTableData>)e.NewValue;
    if (objNewValue != null)
    {
        objNewValue.CollectionChanged += table.OnTableData_CollectionChanged;
    }
}
```

CheckBoxTableData class

```cs
    public class CheckBoxTableData : DependencyObject
    {
        public bool? IsCheckBoxChecked
        {
            get { return (bool?)GetValue(IsCheckBoxCheckedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsCheckBoxCheckedProperty, value); }
        }
        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsCheckBoxChecked.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckBoxCheckedProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register("IsCheckBoxChecked", typeof(bool?), typeof(CheckBoxTableData), new PropertyMetadata(true));

        public int GridRow
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(GridRowProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GridRowProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for GridRow.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty GridRowProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register("GridRow", typeof(int), typeof(CheckBoxTableData), new PropertyMetadata(0));

        public int GridColumn
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(GridColumnProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GridColumnProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for GridColumn.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty GridColumnProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register("GridColumn", typeof(int), typeof(CheckBoxTableData), new PropertyMetadata(0));
    }
}
```

Usage in a window:

```xaml
<Window x:Class="WPFNotWorkingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFNotWorkingTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Click Me" Click="Button_Click" Margin="5"/>
        <local:CheckBoxTable Grid.Row="1" CheckBoxPerRow="10">
            <local:CheckBoxTable.CheckBoxData>
                <local:CheckBoxTableData IsCheckBoxChecked="True"/>
                <local:CheckBoxTableData IsCheckBoxChecked="False"/>
                <local:CheckBoxTableData IsCheckBoxChecked="{Binding CheckMyBinding}"/>
            </local:CheckBoxTable.CheckBoxData>
        </local:CheckBoxTable>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.cs

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public bool? CheckMyBinding
    {
        get { return (bool?)GetValue(CheckMyBindingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CheckMyBindingProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CheckMyBinding.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckMyBindingProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("CheckMyBinding", typeof(bool?), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false));


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckMyBinding == true)
        {
            CheckMyBinding = false;
        }
        else
        {
            CheckMyBinding = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Clicking the button and executing the handler does NOT toggle the IsChecked for the CheckBox. The problem seems to be the binding in the Window and not the User Control and I have wracked my brain trying to figure out why.

Comment: @Manfred I want to make the user control re-usable and able to use the binding in the MainWindow as-is.  Is there a way to modify the Custom User Control such that the individual checkboxes within the ItemsControl can have their exposed dependency properties targeted by the user supplied binding?

Comment: @The problem is not with the control, the problem is that you are trying to set a Binding on your Data directly. No matter how you do this, you will always have to specify the DataContext manually because it's not part of the visual tree.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your `CheckBoxTableData` has no way of knowing about your `MainWindow`. The CheckBoxes generated by the ItemsControl in `CheckBoxTable` each have an instance of `CheckBoxData` as their DataSource. The `CheckBoxTableData` however don't have a DataContext of their own and you can't use a `RelativeSource` because they are not part of the visual or logical tree of your application.

The XAML designer may make it look like it works (showing autocomplete and all), but that's just because it doesn't know how exactly your control works.

You could work around this by setting this Binding manually in your code like this:

```
CheckBoxTableData tableData = new CheckBoxTableData();
BindingOperations.SetBinding(tableData, CheckBoxTableData.IsCheckBoxCheckedProperty,
    new Binding("CheckMyBinding") {Source = this}); // this = MainWindow

checkBoxTable.CheckBoxData = new ObservableCollection<CheckBoxTableData>();
checkBoxTable.CheckBoxData.Add(tableData);
```

[image: Button toggling CheckBox]

However it would be a lot cleaner to take care of this in your ViewModel instead of adding that property to the MainWindow.